# my '.png' image not work for resize image code in php

Tags: php

when i pass a jpg file to `imgsize.php?w=100&h=100&img=powered_by.jpg` then its work well
but i pass a png file to `imgsize.php?w=100&h=100&img=mengo.png` it's not working

my imgsize.php file code is

```
$extension = pathinfo($_GET['img']);
$extension = $extension[extension];
if ($extension == "jpg" || $extension == "jpeg" || $extension == "JPG") {
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
}
if ($extension == "png") {
    header("Content-type: image/png");
}
if ($extension == "gif") {
    header("Content-type: image/gif");
}
$img     = $_GET['img'];
$nwidth  = $_GET['w'];
$nheight = $_GET['h'];
$img2    = imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['img']);
$width   = imagesx($img2);
$height  = imagesy($img2);
$ratio   = $width / $height;
$new_nwidth  = $nwidth;
$new_nheight = floor($height * ($nwidth / $width));
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($img) or $im = imagecreatefrompng($img) or $im = imagecreatefromgif($img) or $im = false;
if (!$im) {
} else {
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($new_nwidth, $new_nheight);
    imagealphablending($thumb, false);
    imagesavealpha($thumb, true);
    $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($thumb, 255, 255, 255, 127);
    imagefilledrectangle($thumb, 0, 0, $new_nwidth, $new_nheight, $transparent);
    imagecopyresized($thumb, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_nwidth, $new_nheight, $width, $height);
    if ($extension == "jpg" || $extension == "jpeg" || $extension == "JPG") {
        imagejpeg($thumb, null, 100);
    }
    if ($extension == "png") {
        imagepng($thumb, null, 9);
    }
    if ($extension == "gif") {
        imagegif($thumb, null, 100);
    }
}
```

any solution for it ? its display blank image when i pass it out a png file

Comment: look at the function names then think png is not jpeg but maybe the manual has the same functions for png.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have checked for the extension in if else condition to generate header the same way you would have to check for creating $img2 like

```
if ($extension == "jpg" || $extension == "jpeg" || $extension == "JPG") {
    $img2    = imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['img']);
}
if ($extension == "png") {
    $img2    = imagecreatefrompng($_GET['img']);
}
if ($extension == "gif") {
    $img2    = imagecreatefromgif($_GET['img']);
}
```

One another thing i would like to add for your info is that check for image mime type rather that checking extension. for that you can user getimagesize function, which return an array and you can check for mime type by $retun_array['mime'].

PNG images often creates problem if not created or stored properly. Corrupt images may cause this problem too. Hope this may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I leave you my code for thumbnail images and save them into a destination folder

```
    function thumbail($forcedwidth, $forcedheight, $sourcefile, $destfile){
    $fw = $forcedwidth;
    $fh = $forcedheight;
    $is = getimagesize( $sourcefile );
    $ancho = $is[0];
    $alto = $is[1];
    if($ancho > $forcedwidth) { 
        $ancho2 = $forcedwidth;
        $por = (100 * $forcedwidth)/$ancho;
        $alto2 = ($alto * $por)/100;
        $t = 1;
    }else{
        $ancho2 = $ancho;
        $alto2 = $alto;
        $t = 2;
    }

    if($alto > $forcedheight) { 
        $alto2 = $forcedheight;
        $por = (100 * $forcedheight)/$alto;
        $ancho2 = ($ancho * $por)/100;
        $t = 1;
    }else{
        $ancho2 = $ancho;
        $alto2 = $alto;
    }
    if ($t == 1){
        $img_src = imagecreatefromjpeg( $sourcefile );
        $img_dst = imagecreatetruecolor( $ancho2, $alto2 );
        imagecopyresampled( $img_dst, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $ancho2, $alto2, $is[0], $is[1] );
        if(!imagejpeg($img_dst, $destfile, 90 )){
            exit();
        }
    }else if ($t == 2){
        copy( $sourcefile, $destfile );
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry Ernesto i don't need to save image, but i need so just dynamically resize them - thanks

Comment: @Toms just modify that doment and when you do copy() just return the image